# Upgrade JBOSS 6.2 to JBOSS 7.0.8

Tags: linux, jboss

I'm trying to do this task but I am not able to find documentation that could guide me on how to accomplish this.

I've been reading this:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Installation_Guide/sect-Upgrading_JBoss_EAP_6.html

From the looks of it seems like this is the path I have to take:
JBOSS 6.2 to 6.4 minor upgrade
JBOSS 6.4 to 7.0 major upgrade (I can use jboss migration tool for this)
JBOSS 7.0 to 7.0.8 patch

My question is do I have to go to 6.2 to 6.3 and then 6.4? or can I go from 6.2 to 6.4 right of away?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually really easy.

1)I upgraded JBOSS 6.2 -> 6.4.
-This is done by copying the domain, standalone and custom modules directories. Once I copied everything I then ran the service: service jboss restart

2)I download the JBOSS migration tool to update from JBOSS 6.4 -> 7.0
-I follow the instructions and it was just a simple command. Where you specify the source and target directory.

3)Did some custom changes to the standalone.xml configuration and ran the service.

DONE :)